# How to use Lookbackapi to fetch all the _PreviousValues of a field

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I am trying to get all the "_PreviousValues" of a field.

For example, the state of a defect have changed from "Open" => "Fixed" => "Closed".

I would like to get all history of the state, but not just the previous value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LookbackAPI returns historic versions (snapshots) of objects. To get a history of state transitions you need to get all snapshots where transition happened, which can be achieved by 
using `"_PreviousValues.State":{"$exists":true}` condition.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/111/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"Project":222,"_TypeHierarchy":"Defect","_PreviousValues.State":{"$exists":true}}&fields=["ObjectID","_ValidFrom","_ValidTo","FormattedID","State","_PreviousValues.State"]&hydrate=["State","_PreviousValues.State"]&compress=true
```

Comment: Follow up:
I managed to get the data using the lookbackapi based on the selected release(release combobox). 
Now, I am trying to display the parsed data using a grid.
When the select event fires from the combobox, it takes 2-3 seconds for the grid to display the loading... gif. I am wondering if there is a way to display that loading gif as soon as the select event fires.

Comment: Found the setLoading function on the grid. THANKS